# Win32 Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I am getting a very annoying exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll.

Tried every google stuff but in vain.

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses(Environment.MachineName))
{
    try
    {
        foreach (ProcessModule pm in p.Modules)
        {
            FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, pm.FileName);

            stack.Push(pm.FileName.ToString());    
        }
    }
    catch (Win32Exception w)
    {
        Console.Write(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code so that the entire block is tagged, and tell us what the exception text is.

Comment: It may also help if you provide some context. What's your goal here?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to open a handle to every module in every process on the system. Not only will you not have the permissions to do this, you also can't enumerate the modules of the System process (i.e. the kernel).

You should simply skip over the ones you don't have access to, because you won't be able to do anything with them anyway.

Comment: @ Polynomial:Buddy I am trying to build an Antivirus(I know a huge thing) and with this I including rootkit scan feature which scans dll files of processes.Any help?

Comment: I know better than most how big an AV project is in C#, because I actually wrote one myself for my university final project. The only real way to do anything useful as an AV is to have a kernel-mode driver written in C and interface with your C# engine using mutexes, DeviceIoControl and AllocHGlobal. Checking for hooks and injected DLLs in user-mode will just result in failure. In user-mode you're confined to what the Win32 API will let you do, so you face the same restrictions as user-mode malware. In kernel-mode you're not confined to anything.